# RandomeForestRegressor - unhashable type: 'Int64Index' error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, random-forest

I am fitting a model to predict a truth value using a `RandomForestRegressor` in `Python` of the [three column dataset](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4Ajk8jGD1OxSEl2cnF6TC1lUXM) (click the link to download the full `CSV`-dataset formatted as in the following

```
t_stamp,X,Y
0.000543,0,10
0.000575,0,10
0.041324,1,10
0.041331,2,10
0.041336,3,10
0.04134,4,10
0.041345,5,10
0.04135,6,10
0.041354,7,10
```

Here is how we do the prediction.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob, os
from io import StringIO
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import math
from math import sqrt
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, glob.glob(os.path.join('', "data.csv"))))

for i in range(1,10):
    df['X_t'+str(i)] = df['X'].shift(i)

print(df)

df.dropna(inplace=True)

X = pd.DataFrame({ 'X_%d'%i : df['X'].shift(i) for i in range(10)}).apply(np.nan_to_num, axis=0).values
y = df['Y'].values

train_index, test_index = train_test_split(df.index, test_size=0.40)

X_train = df.X[[train_index]]
y_train = df.Y[[train_index]]
X_test = df.X[[test_index]]
y_test = df.Y[[test_index]]


#X_train = df.X[train_index].values
#y_train = df.Y[train_index].values
#X_train = df.X[test_index].values
#y_test = df.Y[test_index].values


#X = X[:, None]
#y = df['Y'][:, None]
print(X.shape)
print(df['Y'].shape)

print()
print("Size of X_train:",(len(X_train)))
print("Size of Y_train:",(len(X_train)))
print("Size of X_test:",(len(X_test)))
print("Size of Y_test:",(len(y_test)))

print()
reg = RandomForestRegressor(criterion='mse')
reg.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

However, when i do `reg.fit(X_train,y_train)` - i am getting this error

```
    raise TypeError("unhashable type: %r" % type(self).__name__)

TypeError: unhashable type: 'Int64Index'
```

How do we fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you comment out `.values` code? That seems correct.

Comment: In that case, we will get another error `"number of samples=%d" % (len(y), n_samples))

ValueError: Number of labels=155113 does not match number of samples=1` and when we do `print(X_train.shape)` and `print(y_train.shape)`  `(103410,)` and 
`(155113,)` respectively.

Comment: Have you tried changing your train test split to: `X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.40)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem here is that your train test split isn't right. You can get train test split to output 4 new objects, X_train, X_test, y_train and y_test, just like you try to apply after splitting in your code. I would set up your data like:

```
X = df.drop('Y', axis=1)
y = df['Y']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.40)
```

Then you will be able to apply these to your model.

Comment: but that gives me another error `raise ValueError("x and y must have same first dimension")

ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension` when i try to `fig, ax = plt.subplots()
#df.plot(x='time', y='Y', ax=ax)
ax.plot(df['time'].values, df['Y'].values)

ax.plot(df['time'].values, modelPred_test)`

Comment: That's an error with matplotlib though, none of that is in your original question with the example code given. If I were to make a guess, I'd say that df['time'].values is not the same length as modelPred_test (whatever that is.)

Comment: You'll need to either add it to your code (for example, where modelPred_test is created) or ask a new question, you need to see the shape of modelPred_test, remember that you've split your dataset out into a test set that is 40% of the original df, so test data obviously won't be the same size as the original data set.